# finding minimum value between 1 value and a column

Tags: excel, minimum

Im trying to find the minimum value between some constant and a column of values. Ideally i would like to return the row number so i can reference a different column.

normally with code (such as Matlab) it was just be as simple as

```
[minVal, minIdx] = min(abs(constant - arrayOfNumbers))
```

Then just use the index returned to reference the correct column.

How can i do this in excel?

with a constant of 4184.

```
1  Col A  Col B 
2  5040   -0.29
3  4840   -0.41
4  4620   -0.55
5  4450   -0.67
6  4200   -0.86
7  4050   -1
8  3970   -1.11
9  3880   -1.25
10 3850   -1.3
```

the minimum absolute difference will be abs(4184 - 4200) = 16 at row 6. Hence i would like to reference B(6) to return -0.86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say your value you want to test against (`4184`) is in cell `D1`.

First step, find the minimum absolute difference: put this formula is say cell `E1` as an array formula (accept with Ctrl-Alt-Enter).

```
=MIN(IFERROR(ABS(A:A-$D$1),""))
```

Then find the row this value is in: put this formula in cell `F1` as a normal formula

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(D1-E1,A:A,0),MATCH(D1+E1,A:A,0))
```

Note 1: `IFERROR` function requires Excel 2007 or later

Note 2: if you don't want to have the intermediate formula, you can combine them (as an array formula), but this does repeat the `MIN(...)` part

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(D1-MIN(IFERROR(ABS(A:A-$D$1),"")),A:A,0),MATCH(D1+MIN(IFERROR(ABS(A:A-$D$1),"")),A:A,0))
```

Comment: Just for clarity, to re-write the array formula for returning the row number of the min value by using the names given in the OP example: `=IFERROR(MATCH(constant-MIN(IFERROR(ABS(arrayOfNumbers-constant),"")),arrayOfNumbers,0),MATCH(constant+MIN(IFERROR(ABS(arrayOfNumbers-constant),"")),arrayOfNumbers,0))`

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the row #, or can you just use the resulting -0.86?  If you just want the -0.86, you could use the vlookup function, since it appears your data is already sorted.